# JS сгруппировать фрагменты текста

Tags: javascript

У меня есть текст такого вида:

```
<div class="content">
    <h3>Заголовок 1</h3>
    <h2>Подзаголовок 1</h2>
    <p>Параграф 1</p>

    <h3>Заголовок 2</h3>
    <h2>Подзаголовок 2</h2>
    <p>Параграф 2</p>
    <p>Параграф 2</p>
</div>
```

Как можно обернуть фрагменты текста дополнительным div? Чтобы получилось так:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Заголовок 1</h3>
        <h2>Подзаголовок 1</h2>
        <p>Параграф 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Заголовок 2</h3>
        <h2>Подзаголовок 2</h2>
        <p>Параграф 2</p>
        <p>Параграф 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ключевым элементом для разделения является заголовок h3. Сколько этих заголовков на странице, столько обёрток и должно быть. Обёртка должна включать сам заголовок h3, следующий за ним h2 и все параграфы до следующего h3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type $contentList = NodeListOf<Element>
type $isTarget = (node: Node) => boolean
type $genEl = () => Element

type $a = (contentList: $contentList, isTarget: $isTarget, genEl: $genEl) => void
type $b = (element: Element, isTarget: $isTarget, genEl: $genEl) => void

const a: $a = (contentList, isTarget, genEl) => {
    contentList.forEach(el => b(el, isTarget, genEl))
}
const b: $b = (element, isTarget, genEl) => {
    const childNodeList = Array.from(element.childNodes) // !important `Array.from`
    let lastConteiner: Element | null = null
    childNodeList.forEach(childNode => {
        const _isTarget = isTarget(childNode)
        const _isNotTarget = !_isTarget
        if (lastConteiner && _isNotTarget) { // !important this first
            lastConteiner.appendChild(childNode)
        } else if (_isTarget) { // !important this second
            lastConteiner = genEl()
            childNode.replaceWith(lastConteiner)
            lastConteiner.appendChild(childNode)
        }
    })
}
```

```js
const a=(a,c,l)=>{a.forEach(a=>b(a,c,l))},b=(a,c,l)=>{const o=Array.from(a.childNodes);let d=null;o.forEach(a=>{const o=c(a);d&&!o?d.appendChild(a):o&&(d=l(),a.replaceWith(d),d.appendChild(a))})};

void function MAIN() {
    const { nodeName } = document.createElement('h3')
    // -,-
    a(
        document.querySelectorAll('.content')
        , node => nodeName === node.nodeName
        , () => {
            const div = document.createElement('div')
            div.className = 'dd'
            return div
        }
    )
}();
```

```css
.dd {
border: dashed 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <p>Параграф 0</p>
    <p>Параграф 0</p>
    <p>Параграф 0</p>

    <h3>Заголовок 1</h3>
    <h2>Подзаголовок 1</h2>
    <p>Параграф 1</p>

    <h3>Заголовок 2</h3>
    <h2>Подзаголовок 2</h2>
    <p>Параграф 2</p>
    <p>Параграф 2</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <p>Параграф 0</p>
    <p>Параграф 0</p>
    <p>Параграф 0</p>

    <h3>Заголовок 1</h3>
    <h2>Подзаголовок 1</h2>
    <p>Параграф 1</p>

    <h3>Заголовок 2</h3>
    <h2>Подзаголовок 2</h2>
    <p>Параграф 2</p>
    <p>Параграф 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: красивое решение. Только вместо `dd` - `wrap`. Плюсик.

Comment: qwabra, благодарю за помощь! Смогу поработать с этим скриптом через пару дней.

Comment: qwabra, здравствуйте! Можете помочь мне разобраться со скриптом? Прокомментируйте, что в нём происходит? Я пытаюсь разобраться самостоятельно и понять его.

Comment: Сейчас использую скрипт "как есть" на сайте, он хорошо работает. В контейнере .content начали появляться блоки aside, и он их захватывает тоже. Хочу подредактировать скрипт, для этого мне нужно в нём разобраться. Пока сложновато.

Comment: @ovseo, ?а так: https://vk.cc/an7bKb

Comment: Буду разбираться, спасибо!)